# Silly errors (beginner)

Tags: android, class

I have a first activity ("Home"), with two buttons: one is called About and leads to activity About and the second is named List and leads to the activity List.

Manifest.xml should be fine, but I get a load of tiny petty errors I can't fix up by myself, regrettably.

Home.class is the following

```
Public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Button AboutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.About);

    AboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){

        @Override
                public void onClick(View view); {
            Intent openAbout = new Intent(Home.this, About.class);
            startActivity(openAbout);
        }
    }

    Button ListButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.List);

    ListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener());{

        @Override
                public void onClick(View view); {
            Intent openList = new Intent(Home.this, List.class);
            startActivity(openList);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

while About.class is like this

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    Button ReturnButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Return);

    ReturnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent returnhome = new Intent(About.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(returnhome);

        }


        public void onClick(View view); {
            Intent returnhome = new Intent(About.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(returnhome);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_about, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and List is like this:

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    Button ReturnButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Return);

    ReturnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)   {
            Intent returnhome = new Intent(About.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(returnhome);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I get lot of red light bulbs, saying, for instance that ")" or ";" is expected or (worse) onClickListener cannot be resolved

Last but not least: I copied this code online and I was wondering why after "View" there is a "view"; what does it mean?

Comment: `I get lot of red light bulbs, saying, for instance that ")" or ";" is expected` - Add them.       ... (skipped) ...      `public void onClick(View view)` Here is expected an object of type `View`, which is named `view`.

Comment: And you have a DUPLICATE `onClick()` in your About Class. The second one not only must not be there, but also misses the `@Override` attribute. Apart of that, there's an extra semicolon after its signature: `public void onClick(View view); {`, which is ANOTHER error.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein for the record. Code Review is not intended for broken code. As such this question is horribly off-topic for codereview

Comment: @Vogel612 It's also so horribly off-topic for HERE... Since it's really a BUNCH of errors, not only a SPECIFIC issue.

Comment: I never said it wasn't :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and I see fails everywhere... let me explain you what's going on ...

### HOME CLASS

1.- You have to remove the ")"

2.- You don't have to ";" when you call `onClick()`

3.- When you are don on your `onClick()` **NOW** you have to close it, you missed the ");"

```
AboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){ //<-- Just remove one

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view); { //<-- Remove this ";"
            Intent openAbout = new Intent(Home.this, About.class);
            startActivity(openAbout);
        }
    }//Here goes ");"
```

4.- The `ListButton` has the same issues so just fix it as you will fix the first one.

### ABOUT CLASS

1.-On this case you have the `setOnClickListener()` ok, **BUT** why you have two `onClick(View view)`? It's not necessary just remove one of them.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    Button ReturnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Return);

    ReturnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent returnhome = new Intent(About.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(returnhome);

        }
    });
}
```

### LIST CLASS

1.-Well in your List class you have made the same error as the first one... Your `onClickListener()` it's wrong.

2.-Once again you included an unnecessary ")" on `new View.OnClickListener()` just remove it,

3.-Another fail that I'm seeing is that you are trying to make an `Intent` but you are refering that you are on `About.this` and you are NOT. You are on List class so you have ot put `List.this` because the first parameter refers :

> A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)

[More information about `Intents`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

4.- You need to close again the `setOnClickListener()`

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    Button ReturnButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Return);

    ReturnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){ //<-- remove one ")"

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)   {
            Intent returnhome = new Intent(About.this, Home.class); //<-- Remove About.this and put List.this
            startActivity(returnhome);
        }
    }//<-- Close the setOnClickListener() with ");"
}
```

---

It's okay guy, this is your first question and I'll answer it, but **NOW** as I've made the favor to take my time and explain to you what was wrong on your code take your time to :

[How do I as a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[Learn some Android basics](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1MSNA_enES652ES652&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Learn+Android)

And the most **IMPORTANT THING**

DO NOT COPY PASTE AN INTERNET CODE if you don't know the basics, I mean you can copy paste the code, but you'll face with this problem every time you do this, so first of all read the tutorial, make an examples, and you'll improve every day.

Comment: Hi Skizo,Yes, thank you very much for your time!
I see that every time I copy and paste a code, I got error and most of the times it's because I can't figure out what is a pat of the code and what is not. Do you have any hint at that?

Comment: Just read manuals, start from the start and don't try big things when you don't know too much. Just read about [Learn Java](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1MSNA_enES652ES652&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Learn+java) and then you can start with Android. Btw if my answer helped to you just mark it as a correct is the check green.

Comment: Mark it as a correct @MarcoDeRoni if I solved your problem you just have to click on the check green

Comment: Do you still having problems?

Comment: Hi @Skizo, thanks again for the help. Sadly not, as some bits of code are not exactly recognised, but you have fully answered my question, I've +1ed your answer, thanks heaps again

Comment: If you need help just let me know :) and if I solved your problem mark this question as a solved clicking on the green check to accept my answer  :)

Comment: Hi @Skyzo, yes, there's something you can do. Everytime I start a handbook on Android, I get lost in ravelings and I'd need the best tutorial ever. If I simply want to open a new activity, I look for codes online and they all vary or don't explain what is being done (why "View"? Why onClickListener is marked in red? etc). Do you have any place where I could find a smooth guide, by chance?

Comment: @MarcoDeRoni Open it as follows : `Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class); 
            startActivity(i);`

Comment: yes, but the activity must start on a certain event (click on the button), therefore I need to identify the button by the id (check) and define the event of the click, correct?
And do I need to put the Override in a particular order, with respect to other Overrides in the class?

Comment: What are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: 1st one; moreover, the setOnClickListener is considered as a non-static method

Comment: There's a trick when you want to make a `setOnClickListener()` you put for example `mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClic` and you press tab key and it creates the onClick solo

Comment: I typed Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Try this : `btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class); startActivity(i);
       }
});`